# Why is arg $0$ not defined for any branch?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Of course, any branch of arg $z$ must have a jump of $2\pi$ somewhere. The branch depicted in Fig. 1.10(b) is discontinuous on the positive real axis, taking values from the interval $(0,2\pi]$. The branch in Fig. 1.10(c) has the same branch cut but selects values from the interval $(2\pi,4\pi]$
>
> The notation arg$_{\tau}z$ is used for the branch of arg $z$ taking values from the interval $(\tau, \tau + 2\pi]$. Thus arg$_{-\pi}z$ is the principal value Arg $z$, and the branches depicted in Fig. 1.10(b) and 1.10(c), respectively, are arg$_{0}z$ and arg$_{2\pi}z$. Note that arg $0$ cannot be sensibly defined for any branch.

I 'm having trouble understanding why arg $0$ can't be defined for any branch. What if we chose the interval $(-2\pi,0]$, for example?

I've also included the images mentioned in the above text.
[image][image]

Comment: $0=0e^{it}$ for **any** $t$. So you could say that any real number is an "argument" for $0$. Why bother singling any of them out/

Comment: $0=0+i.0$ so $arg(0)=tan^{-1}\frac{0}{0}$ is not defined.